# Accessing class object

Tags: c++

I have three .h and three .cpp files along with them.

I have made an object of a class in the first .h (say 1.h) in a class that is in 2.h. I want to use that class object in my 3.cpp.

1.h

```
class One
{ 
   bool pressed;
   ...
}
```

2.h

```
#include "1.h"
Class Two
{
public:
    One object;
    ...
}
```

3.h

```
#include "2.h"
Class Three
{ ...
}
```

3.cpp

```
#include "3.h"

void Three::OnPressed()
{
   object.pressed = true;
}
```

It allows me to make the object without complaints, however, my program gives this error when run:

error C2065 'object': undeclared identifier

I don't think this is a hard question, but I had trouble trying to explain my problem through a search bar. If you could help me out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Show the code that the compiler is complaining about along with the exact message it gives you about it.

Comment: `Object` is indeed undeclared. All you have is `object`.

Comment: You have declared two of your classes as ``Class`` with a capital C. C++ is case sensitive, so this is different from ``class`` in ``1.h``. You may also have noted that it is colored differently in the examples above.

Comment: @Arkadiy Sorry, that was a typo on my question, not the code itself. I edited it as NathanOliver requested and fixed that issue.

Comment: Did you mean to make `Two` the base class of `Three`? As it stands, `Three` has no member named `object`, only `Two` has such member.

Comment: Is `object` not usable by `Three` then? I don't want it to be the base class, but I absolutely want access to it.

Comment: ***Is object not usable by Three then?*** If there is no relationship between Two and Three how would Three know which instance of Two to access object?

Answer (score 1):

`OnPressed()` is a member of `Three`, but `Three` does not derive from `Two`, so `Three` does not have any `object` member that `OnPressed()` can access.  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

You would need to either:

1. make `Three` derive from `Two`

   ```
   class Three : public Two
   ```
2. give `Three` a member that is an instance of `One` (just like you did with `Two`):

   ```
   class Three
   {
   public:
       One object;
       void OnPressed();
       ...
   };

   void Three::OnPressed()
   {
       object.pressed = true;
   }
   ```

   Or give it an instance of `Two`:

   ```
   class Three
   {
   public:
       Two object2;
       void OnPressed();
       ...
   };

   void Three::OnPressed()
   {
       object2.object.pressed = true;
   }
   ```